# On the .org repo, can your plugin name/slug contain "WooCommerce"

Tags: plugin-development

I know they won't let you call a plugin **WordPress-xxx**, but they will allow **WP-xxx**. What are the rules surrounding **WooCommerce**?

Comment: Note: WooCommerce is a company that is owned by Automattic, the parent company that owns the WordPress ecosystem. And I know you love to make off topic votes about Woo [even though it's the same company they have manipulated you into forgetting that]. It's not 'off topic'. This is specifically about how the .org related to its own internal naming conventions.I'm not asking about developing Woo stuff, I'm asking how the non-profit .org regulates copyrights to companies horizontal in their own corporate structure. It's specifically ON TOPIC about the non-profit .org WordPress.

Comment: Reading the [On-Topic help page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I don't see anything about the .org naming conventions or copyright/trademark policies. Thus my off-topic vote.

Comment: The third line in your link is "theme and plugin development". I'm asking about the rules for the .org plugin directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting this answer because the accepted answer is slightly misleading, as it implies that you cannot use the trademarked name at all.  While not 100% wrong, it's also not 100% right.

It is correct that unless **you** are WooCommerce, you can't call your plugin "WooCommerce Cool Add-on".  But you ***can*** call it "Cool Add-on for WooCommerce."  See "[Why can’t I use someone’s trademark/brand as my plugin name?](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-developer-faq/#why-cant-i-use-someones-trademarkbrand-as-my-plugin-name)"

Also, if you're submitting to the .org repo and you are concerned about making sure your naming convention is correct/acceptable/valid, just submit it the way you interpret the rules. If it's unacceptable, *they **will** tell you* and then you adjust it to be approved. OR, just get on the #PluginReview Slack channel and ask up front.  @Ipstenu and @otto42 can give you a solid thumbs up/down on whether your name will pass muster.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Plugin Developer FAQ](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-developer-faq/#why-did-i-get-a-different-slug-than-i-was-told)

> For example, if you submit “WooCommerce Tango Salsa Add-on” that would make your slug `woocommerce-tango-salsa-add-on` by default. If you don’t work for WooCommerce, we would just change that to `woo-tango-salsa-add-on` for you.

It appears that the policy is, if you **don't work for WooCommerce**, you aren't supposed to use "WooCommerce" in your plugin names.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research on the subject. The answer is that there is no consistent policy from Automattic on this. I have been personally threatened by Automattic for using "WordPress", but not "WooCommerce". Specifically, they are not defending "WooCommerce" on their own controlled marketplace:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/jilt-for-woocommerce/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pos/

So it looks to me that you can call a plugin "WooCommerce" all day and they have chosen to only defend the copyright in certain cases. I'll consider this post a notice on the subject. I intend to use the term "WooCommerce" commercially, which I consider in the public domain, as the copyright is not defended. [see you in court!]. Have a nice day.